# Remove from JSON propery but left their values

Tags: c#, javascript, json, string, properties

I have JSON :

```
[
  {
    "Position": "ProjectManager",
    "Salary": 2000
  },
  {
    "Position": "BusinessAnalyst",
    "Salary": 2001
  },
  {
    "Position": "TechnicalLead",
    "Salary": 2002
  },
  {
    "Position": "SeniorSoftwareEngineer",
    "Salary": 2003
  },
  {
    "Position": "SoftwareEngineer",
    "Salary": 2004
  },
  {
    "Position": "JuniorSoftwareEngineer",
    "Salary": 2005
  },
  {
    "Position": "UIUXEngineer",
    "Salary": 2006
  },
  {
    "Position": "QALead",
    "Salary": 2007
  },
  {
    "Position": "SeniorQAEngineer",
    "Salary": 2008
  },
  {
    "Position": "QAEngineer",
    "Salary": 2009
  },
  {
    "Position": "JuniorQAEngineer",
    "Salary": 2010
  },
  {
    "Position": "SeniorAutomationEngineer",
    "Salary": 2011
  },
  {
    "Position": "AutomationEngineer",
    "Salary": 2012
  },
  {
    "Position": "JuniorAutomationEngineer",
    "Salary": 2013
  }
]
```

But I need to convert it into this example :

```
{
  "ProjectManager": "2000",
    "BusinessAnalyst": "2001",
    "TechnicalLead": "2002",
    "SeniorSoftwareEngineer": "2003",
    "SoftwareEngineer": "2004",
    "JuniorSoftwareEngineer": "2005",
    "UIUXEngineer": "2006",
    "QALead": "2007",
    "SeniorQAEngineer": "2008",
    "QAEngineer": "2009",
    "JuniorQAEngineer": "2010",
    "SeniorAutomationEngineer": "2011",
    "AutomationEngineer": "2012",
    "JuniorAutomationEngineer": "2013"
}
```

As you see in 2nd example i have just values and no properties. How can i do this? (Currentrly my idea is to parse Json as string and remove all tokens that match "Position :" or "Salary :")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be iterating each object in the array and populate a dictionary:

```
// Using JSON.NET you can deserialize the JSON array as an enumerable 
// of dynamically-typed objects (i.e. your array)
IEnumerable<dynamic> employees = JsonConvert
                                   .DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<dynamic>>
                                   (
                                       jsonText
                                   );

Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

foreach(dynamic employee in employees) 
{
    values.Add((string)employee.Position, (object)employee.Salary);
}

// .NET dictionaries are deserialized into JSON objects!
string convertedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
```

[Check a working sample on .NET Fiddle!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fGyr2Y)

### Update

And if you want a one-liner LINQ extension methods-based solution, what about:

```
string convertedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject
(
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<dynamic>>(jsonText)
        .ToDictionary(employee => employee.Position, employee => employee.Salary)
);
```

Comment: @user3770925 No problem. Check my update, you might be able to simplify even more the solution! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to doo so much a stuff.
I can metioned a method.

let your json one is probjson and result asresjson

```
var arr=new [];
var res=new { arr }
    for(var i in probjson.length){

var position=probjson[i].Position;
var salary=probjson[i].Salary;

var v = new { position=salary  }
res.arr.add(V);

}
```

this not a complete one

plz try to get a idea.
thankz